# Variable used. But still the error says "variable x not used"

Tags: arrays, go

I am new to Golang. I am trying to clean duplicates. When I try to build the go code, I get this error.

```
    utils.go:60:62: cleanedTransactedFrom declared and not used
```

I made sure that they are used. I am sorry about the naming conventions. I am very new to Golang, so I am yet to follow the conventions. As of now consider `types.TransactedFrom` is a simple struct that has `ID` and `TimeStamp`.

```
  func removeDuplicates(TransactedFrom [][]types.TransactedFrom) [][]types.TransactedFrom {
    cleanedTransactedFrom := [][]types.TransactedFrom{}
    equal := true
    for index, singleTransactedFrom := range TransactedFrom {
      for _, selectedTransactedFrom := range TransactedFrom[index:] {
        if reflect.DeepEqual(singleTransactedFrom, selectedTransactedFrom) {
          equal = false
        }
      }
      if equal {
        cleanedTransactedFrom := append(cleanedTransactedFrom, singleTransactedFrom)
      }
      equal = true
    }
    return cleanedTransactedFrom
  }
```

Comment: you're creating 2 new variables on `equal := false` and `cleanedTransactedFrom := append...` who are being using on different scopes, remove the `:=` to prevent the creations of a new variable

Comment: @Motakjuq Thank you so much. It worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
equal := false
```

to

```
equal = false
```

because right now you're declaring a new variable in the inner block scope.

Remember than `:=` is both a declaration and an assignment (as noticed by peterSO you have the same problem for another variable and you should probably check your whole code now that you know how it works).

Comment: Thanks it worked.